# should exception's inner class be public or private

Tags: apex, exception, access-modifier

**Scenario:** I have 1 APEX class, in which I have inner class extending exception, as can be seen below:

```
public with sharing class ClassA{
   PUBLIC/PRIVATE class ClassBException extends ClassCException {}
}
```

This ClassBException is only used for ClassA, and ClassA will in turn be used in LWC.

**Question:**
The access modifier where it is in all caps in above code (PUBLIC/PRIVATE) should be public or private?

Note: [this developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) only talks about method or variable but what about the inner classes especially the exception classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a strictly Object-Oriented Programming perspective, it should be `private` (which, you can also just omit, as `private` is the default access). This makes it clear to future code readers/maintainers that this class is only used locally. Functionally speaking, it doesn't matter which access you provide if you only intend to use it in `ClassA`.